# Displaying mysql query result set as a table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to display a query result set as a table on my webpage. The query is not causing any errors, but the script is not producing any output.

I have one table in database (players). This table has 3 rows (id, firstname, lastname).

[Script source code](http://wklej.org/id/659873/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>View Records</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>View Records</h1>

    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set('display_errors','1');

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=records2', 'root', '');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $players = $db->query('SELECT * FROM players');

    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10>";
    echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th></tr>";

    foreach($players->fetchAll() as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['firstname']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    $player->closeCursor();

    echo "</table>";
    ?>      
  </body>
</html>
```

My database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `players` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Comment: Not error display. Only show: View Records from <h1> tag. Not display my data from database

Comment: If you view the resulting source, do you have table rows with empty data?

Comment: No. I have something like this (in browser in website source) <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>View Records</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>View Records</h1>

Comment: If you run the query in your mysql console (or PHPMyAdmin or equivalent), what result do you get? Do you actually have any data in your table?

Comment: If i run the query in phpmyadmin, my query work good. Yes, i have actually data in my table. My website source looks like this: http://wklej.org/id/659917/ (in chrome browser)

Comment: That looks like a parse error then, since your body and html tags are missing, i.e. the PHP crashes. Check your Apache/PHP error logs. You can also try to add a `try...catch` around the database connecting/querying code.

Comment: <table border='1' cellpadding='10> I forget ' . This is right: <table border='1' cellpadding='10'>. Now work ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask PDO for an error message like this:

```
print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: print_r result: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: Ok, so no error. You should also try to [catche errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php). But maybe your table is just empty?

Answer (score 1):

Greetings user1050014 and others. I was able to duplicate the problem that you experienced with this script. I modified the script to work with a database on my machine. The script performed as expected. One change for me was to put the back tick after [cellpadding='10']. This is an honest typo. This should correct your problem.

```
// your original line from your script
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10>";
```

You also had a typo in your call to $player->closeCursor(); (should be $players). I hope that this will be of help to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a single apostrophe here

```
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10>";
```

corrected:

```
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
```